# DatePickerCellEditor resets the time when cell editing starts and stops

Tags: java, swingx, jxtable

I have a `JXTable` with two columns that hold string values and one column that holds a date time value that follows this format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Since I only care about the users changing the date, I thought I'd make use of `DatePickerCellEditor` from the Swingx package with a custom `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`.

So far so good, except the problems start to occur when editing starts. The date part of the datetime is maintained, however, the time portion of it gets reset to "00:00:00" and to make matters worse, when I move to edit another cell, the value that remains in the cell that was being edited is the proper date, but the time at 00:00:00.

In other words, this [image: Before edit] becomes this [image]

I have tried many things to fix this, including overriding the `getTableCellEditorComponent` from `DatePickerCellEditor` and printing the date directly from the `JXDatePicker`. I found out that somewhere along the way, the time part of the day was being reset to "00:00:00". I couldn't find out where. I then tried, within the `getTableCellEditorComponent`, manually setting the date by using `JXDatePicker#setDate` and that also didn't work.

One workaround I found was, inside `getTableCellEditorComponent`, calling `JXDatePicker#getEditor` and manually setting the date there, however, the time part of the cell value still gets reset when editing stops.

```
public class SQLDatePickerCellEditor extends DatePickerCellEditor {

    public SQLDatePickerCellEditor(DateFormat dateFormat) {
        super(dateFormat);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        JXDatePicker picker = (JXDatePicker) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
        picker.getEditor().setText(value.toString());
        System.out.println(picker.getDate()); //this prints the correct date but for some reason at 00:00:00
        return picker;
    }

}
```

Here's the sample code to work with:

```
public class DateForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public DateForm() {
        initComponents();
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        initModel();
    }

    public void initModel() {
        Class<?>[] types = new Class<?>[]{String.class, String.class, Date.class};
        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
            {"John", "Smith", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())}
        };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, new String[]{"Name", "Surname", "Date"}) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types[columnIndex];
            }
        };

        table.setModel(model);
        table.getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DatePickerCellEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
        StringValue sv = new FormatStringValue(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        TableCellRenderer r = new DefaultTableRenderer(sv);
        table.getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(r);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                      
    private void initComponents() {

        scrPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        table = new org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
        scrPane.setViewportView(table);

        getContentPane().add(scrPane, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }                     

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DateForm df = new DateForm();
                df.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrPane;
    private org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable table;               

}
```

Is this behaviour intended? I am aware that `JXDatePicker` is for dates only, but I naturally assumed that it would preserve the time as long as the user didn't change the date.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is the fact that the date value is a `String`, but the editor might be expecting a `Date` value

Comment: No, sadly that's not it. I just changed the data array type to `Object` and gave it a `Date` as its third value but the behaviour remains exactly the same. Either way, for completeness' sake, I just updated the sample code to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh god, I think I did it. After MUCH digging, the problem lays with the `JXMonthView` component that is inside the `JXDatePicker`. In short, it's using the wrong selection model. For it to properly work, we need to instantiate a new `SingleDaySelectionModel` and pass it to the `JXMonthView`.

Documentation for the `JXDatePicker#setDate` method that gave me the answer to my problem:

> Sets the date property.
>
> Does nothing if the ui vetos the new date - as might happen if
>      the code tries to set a date which is unselectable in the 
>      monthView's context. The actual value of the new Date is controlled
>      by the JXMonthView's DateSelectionModel. **The default implementation
>      normalizes the date to the start of the day in the model's calendar's 
>      coordinates, that is all time fields are zeroed. To keep the time fields,
>      configure the monthView with a SingleDaySelectionModel**.

Default initialisation in `JXDatePicker.java` - as you can see, the line we need is commented:

```
private void initMonthView() {
    _monthView = new JXMonthView();
    //        _monthView.setSelectionModel(new SingleDaySelectionModel());
    _monthView.setTraversable(true);
    _monthView.addPropertyChangeListener(getMonthViewListener());
}
```

Since inheriting from `JXDatePicker` wasn't an option, what I did was create a custom CellEditor like so:

```
public class SQLDatePickerCellEditor extends DatePickerCellEditor {

    public SQLDatePickerCellEditor() {
        super(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        datePicker.getMonthView().setSelectionModel(new SingleDaySelectionModel());
    }

}
```

This preserves the time as needed.

Note: I'm using the compiled .jar so I can't edit source files. If using editable source files, naturally the best solution is to simply uncomment the line.